# Binding ng-model to a Service parameter from inside a Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

I keep a data model in a service so that various controllers can use them. Inside the controller I scope it so that elements can bind to it using ng-model:

In the controller:

```
angular.module('hiveApp').controller('weatherController', function($scope, $rootScope, weatherModel, messageService, utilityService, $http, $timeout, $cookies, $window, $controller) {

$scope.weatherModel = weatherModel;
```

Then in the HTML element:

```
<input type="text" id="city" ng-model="weatherModel.city" />
```

So far so good, this works. The problem occurs when I bring a directive into the mix. I have a directive that handles a pair of radio buttons, and makes use of a template. That template attempts to use ng-model to reference that same weatherModel service parameters, however while it works from the HTML in the page itself, the directive template doesn't work:

```
app.directive('radiopair', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: `
        <div style="color:white; float:left">
            <input type="radio" id="metric" name="conversion" value="metric"
                   ng-model="weatherModel.conversion" selected> Metric<br>
            <input type="radio" id="imperial" name="conversion" value="imperial"
                   ng-model="weatherModel.conversion"> Imperial<br>
        </div>
    `,
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('click', function (event) {
            event.currentTarget.selected = true;
            $scope.refreshTable();  
        });
    }       
}
});
```

When I toggle between the two buttons, the ng-model=weatherModel.conversion value never gets updated. I figure this has got to be some scoping issue but I'm hitting a wall as to how to fix it.

Comment: Why did you add a click handler? And what does it do?

Comment: It's really there to refresh an existing table...basically it's a grid and it renders some of the cells differently depending on the setting of the radio buttons, so I put the refresh call there.

Comment: I know that I could just move the template in the directive back into the main HTML body and it would work by using a combination of ng-click (to refresh the table) and ng-model (to set the conversion type) but in this case I was specifically asked to move this bit into a directive so I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do here is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a click handler to invoke the `refreshTable` function, use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive:

```
app.directive('radiopair', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: `
            <div style="color:white; float:left">
                <input type="radio" id="metric" name="conversion" value="metric"
                       ng-change="refreshTable()"
                       ng-model="weatherModel.conversion" selected> Metric<br>
                <input type="radio" id="imperial" name="conversion" value="imperial"
                       ng-change="refreshTable()"
                       ng-model="weatherModel.conversion"> Imperial<br>
            </div>
        `,
        //link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        //    element.on('click', function (event) {
        //        event.currentTarget.selected = true;
        //        $scope.refreshTable();  
        //    });
        //}       
    }
});
```

Avoid manipulating the `select` attribute of `<input>` elements. That should be done by the `ng-model` directive and the `ngModelController`.